# Why was my question about why chess accepts resigning closed as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, exact-duplicates, closed-questions

My question [Why is it acceptable to resign?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/30146/why-is-it-acceptable-to-resign) was closed as a duplicate of an earlier question I asked, [Is it poor sportsmanship to resign immediately after a major blunder early in the game?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/28281/is-it-poor-sportsmanship-to-resign-immediately-after-a-major-blunder-early-in-th) These are not duplicates. The older question asks "Is resigning (in a particular situation) proper chess etiquette?" The new one is getting to a deeper question: "Why does chess have a different viewpoint than most other games/sports about what behavior is considered good sportsmanship?"

Thus I seek an explanation for why the newer question deserves to be closed.

NB: Perhaps the correct answer for this newer question is beyond memory and has just become part of chess culture. If so, I think someone should be given the opportunity to say that.

Answer (score 3):

Seeing as how the question in question is now reopened, this is a resolved matter.